# Mongoose Search By Array in Array Sub Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got some problem in filtering data in mongoose subdocument. I Have collection like this

```
[
    {
        Title : "Some Title",
        Tags : [
            "angular", "html"
        ]
    },
    {
        Title : "Another Title",
        Tags : [
            "css", "html"
        ]
    },
    {
        Title : "Another Title 2",
        Tags : [
            "css"
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get some data by finding match tag. If the tag is "angular" and "html" then I get row 1 (from angular and html) and row 2 (from html). And If the tags is "css", then I get row 2 and 3.

If that possible doing that? I'm using mongoose

Comment: `.find({ "Tags": "css" })` What is the problem? You don't have to do anything special for an array of values, since MongoDB does not care. Unless you mean that you want "all" elements to match. The [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator does that. `.find({ "Tags": { "$all": [ "css", "angular" ] } })`. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Keep in mind that this also works `{ "Tags": [ "angular", "html"] }` but this will not `{ "Tags": [ "html", "angular" ] }` since the order is not exact. That's when you use `$all`. Two different questions I think.

Comment: @neil hey sory, I just forgot somthing in my question. The question I just edited bellow. Thanks for your answer before

Comment: I'm really not sure what exactly your question is. What is your question? As shown in comments, I presume you either A.) Misunderstood that you do not need to supply an "array" in order to match an item in an array B.) The difference between an "exact match" with an "array" as an argument and the usage of the `$all` operator. So it's really hard to answer a question when it is not clear exactly what your question is.